# How to pass an string argument into JS function inside PHP string?

Tags: javascript, php, string, arguments

so I have this PHP code, printing html tables with a button in a for loop:

```
echo "<table><td>".$tablica[$i]['nazwa']."</td>
<td>".$tablica[$i]['koszt']."</td>
<td><button onclick='addDiv()'>ADD</button></td>
</table>";
```

addDiv is a javascript function, and I want to pass a string as an argument to it (preferably from php variable). It works fine without arguments, or with numeric arguments, but single quotes required by JS for string argumnents mess up whole thing.

Cheers,
Amano

Comment: yoy should escape quotes

Comment: Mixing *three different languages* on *one line of code* is just begging for quoting errors.  You may find this to be a lot easier if you separate some of these.

Answer (score 0):

as PHP variabile mean you can assign server side  the $yourVar

```
echo "<table><td>".$tablica[$i]['nazwa']."</td>
  <td>".$tablica[$i]['koszt']."</td>
  <td><button onclick='addDiv(". $yourVar . ")'>ADD</button></td>
  </table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add escape before the quote:

```
echo "<table>
         <tr>         
            <td>".$tablica[$i]['nazwa']."</td>
            <td>".$tablica[$i]['koszt']."</td>
            <td><button onclick=\"addDiv('".$variable_name."')\">ADD</button></td>
         </tr>
      </table>";
```

Comment: Worked - Stack Overflow won't show my upvotes yet as I'm a noob here, so I figured I'd thank you here :)